# System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Email as an Attachment to an Outgoing Email in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

How can an email be attached, as an MSG file, to an outgoing email in CRM 2011?

I have created an html attachment of the email which is OK, but the html attachment has to be viewed in the browser; the preview in Outlook does not display the images.

The problem that I have is that the ActivityMimeAttachment Entity in CRM requires the body to be a Base64 string, which is ok if it is an html string to be the attachment:

```c#
        // UnicodeEncoding had to be used as there were problems with 
        // special char in ASCII
        var bodyArray = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(body);
        body = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bodyArray);
        return body;
```

How can I use a MSG file created from `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` as an attachment or how can I convert a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` email to a Base64String?

Comment: So you want to attach a .msg file to an email in CRM?

Comment: Yes; or find another way to attach an existing email in CRM to an outgoing email. The email that was sent needs to be attached to an automated response email.

Comment: 3 yrs and still no reply. How can I bump this thread?